# How can I find all unmatched records across 2 tables in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have:

```
SELECT * 
FROM recruiter r 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM recruiter_assigned_role rar 
  WHERE recruiter_assigned_role.recruiterUser = recruiter.userId
)
```

I want to find all `recruiter` entries that do not have an associated `recruiter_assigned_role`. But this query gives me an error:

```
17:07:52 Kernel error: ERROR:  
invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "recruiter_assigned_role"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You assigned an alias then didn't use it.

Comment: If you alias a table to `rar` then you can only ever refer to it by the name `rar`.  In the context/scope of that query, the tables `recruiter` and `recruiter_assigned_role` can not be seen, but table references named `r` and `rar` can be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postgres is expecting you to use the defined table's alias:

```
SELECT * 
FROM recruiter r 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM recruiter_assigned_role rar 
  WHERE rar.recruiterUser = r.userId
)
```

Comment: Weird... tells me: `column rar.recruiteruser does not exist`, but it does

Comment: @Shamoon - I can only assume you have your columns correct - to diagnose further suggest you create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) using DB<>Fiddle - you'll likely spot the issue when you do!

Comment: @Shamoon - run `\d recruiter_assigned_role` and copy the results in to your question.  I have no doubt whatsoever that it doesn't contain that column name, but maybe contains a similarly named one.

Answer (score -1):

Your query is syntactically incorrect. Always use joins when you can, it's simpler, faster and easier to read.

```
SELECT r.* 
FROM recruiter r 
LEFT JOIN recruiter_assigned_role rar 
  on (r.userId = rar.recruiterUser)
WHERE
  rar.recruiterUser is null
```

Comment: I disagree on all those points.

Comment: *always use joins* - absolutely not, *always* use the right tool for the job and understand the benefits of each.